# Local call forward with 2 sim cards

Tags: android

It's just impossible to find any information about "local" forwarding with phone, without using the usual network forwarder.

I have idea how it could work, but I need to know if something couldn't be done, even on rooted android.

This how it could work.

We should have:

- Phone A with 2 simcards (X and Z).
- Phone B number - where's we redirect the calls (one default number to forward all calls to)

And the app could work like this:

.
1. Incoming call to phone A (to X simcard). App starts calling (from Z card) to the phone B.

.
2.  If phone B answers the call,

- app answers the call from simcard X,
- connects the sound out from sim X to sim Z in (so phone B could hear what the caller is saying),
- connects the sound out from sim Z to sim X in, (so the caller could hear what the phone B is answering)

  3. When call is ended on sim Z, the app hangs up the phone for sim X too or in reverse.

Basically with the forwarding step, that's it. The app then could do more stuff, like recording, tracking call duration, calls history and more.

This kind of app would be really helpful for businesses, so it's strange that it doesn't exist (I did research).

So the questions are:

- Maybe it wouldn't be possible to call at the same time to another number while we are on another call? But if various spy trackers do that, then it means it is possible?
- Any issues about doing this with 2 sim cards?
- If these spy trackers have all the functionality we need on this app, why no one creates an app like this? Even if it would require a rooted phone - it would still be pretty useful and valuable! There are many lead business trying to track calls, forwarding and manually managing them. Other solutions are pretty expensive.
- If this couldn't be done this way, how could it be done? Maybe connecting 2 phones to computer, then answering and forwarding from one to another within computer? Of course it should be always turned on, but there could be solutions like blueberry and so.

What do you think as experienced android developer? Is it super hard to achieve it? I am web developer and have very little experience on android, so I see it's possible.